# JQ: How do I replace keys and values based on regex match?

Tags: json, key, edit, jq

I have two questions:

1. How can I use jq to search for "name" fields that start with an underscore (like `_RDS_PASSWORD`) and remove the leading underscore (so it becomes `RDS_PASSWORD`)
2. How can I use jq for "name" fields that start with an underscore (like `_RDS_PASSWORD`) and pass the value of the value `cGFzc3dvcmQK` to be decoded via base64? (ex: "cGFzc3dvcmQK" | base64 --decode)

Input:

```
[ 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_DB_NAME", 
    "value": "rds_db_name" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_HOSTNAME", 
    "value": "rds_hostname" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_PORT", 
    "value": "1234" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_USERNAME", 
    "value": "rds_username" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "_RDS_PASSWORD", 
    "value": "cGFzc3dvcmQK" 
  } 
]
```

Desired output:

```
[ 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_DB_NAME", 
    "value": "rds_db_name" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_HOSTNAME", 
    "value": "rds_hostname" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_PORT", 
    "value": "1234" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_USERNAME", 
    "value": "rds_username" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "RDS_PASSWORD", 
    "value": "password" 
  } 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Q1

```
walk( if type=="object" and has("name") and .name[0:1] == "_"
      then .name |= .[1:]
      else . 
      end)
```

If your jq does not have `walk/1` then you can either upgrade to a more recent version of jq than 1.5, or include its `def`, which can be found at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

#### Q2

```
.. | objects | select(has("name") and .name[0:1] == "_") | .value
```

If you are certain that the encoded string was a UTF-8 string, you could use jq's @base64d; otherwise, invoke jq with the -r option and pipe the results to a decoder as you indicated you planned to do.