# JQ key map name to uppercase and remove space

Tags: json, bash, key, jq, uppercase

i'm working in a bash script i have to customize one JSON obj with jq .
I have:

```
[
  {
    "NC dn": "DC=company,DC=org",
    "DSA objectGUID": "df9e8712-98c5-42e4-a020-2e5218404e51",
    "last attempt time": "Wed Jun 10 15:27:42 2020 CEST",
    "last attempt message": "was successful",
    "consecutive failures": 0,
    "last success": "Wed Jun 10 15:27:42 2020 CEST",
    "NTDS DN": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=STEN0002-R2,CN=Servers,CN=TENGIZ,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
    "is deleted": false,
    "DSA": "TENGIZ\\STEN0002-R2"
  },
  {
    "NC dn": "DC=company,DC=org",
    "DSA objectGUID": "d5d168fd-5fc3-4afc-9acc-32c7f10d14a2",
    "last attempt time": "Wed Jun 10 15:27:42 2020 CEST",
    "last attempt message": "was successful",
    "consecutive failures": 0,
    "last success": "Wed Jun 10 15:27:42 2020 CEST",
    "NTDS DN": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SCGPN0002-R2,CN=Servers,CN=POINTE-NOIRE,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
    "is deleted": false,
    "DSA": "POINTE-NOIRE\\SCGPN0002-R2"
  }
]
```

but i need all key with out space and uppercase with {#JSON_KEY} plus CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES value and IS_DELETED value with " "  :

```
[
  {
    "{#NC_DN}": "DC=domain,DC=org",
    "{#DSA_OBJECTGUID}": "df9e8712-98c5-42e4-a020-2e5218404e51",
    "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME}": "Wed Jun 10 15:27:42 2020 CEST",
    "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE}": "was successful",
    "{#CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES}": "0",
    "{#LAST_SUCCESS}": "Wed Jun 10 15:27:42 2020 CEST",
    "{#NTDS_DN}": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=STEN0002-R2,CN=Servers,CN=TENGIZ,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=org",
    "{#IS_DELETED}": "false",
    "{#DSA}": "TENGIZ\\STEN0002-R2"
  },
  {
    "{#NC_DN}": "DC=domain,DC=org",
    "{#DSA_OBJECTGUID}": "d5d168fd-5fc3-4afc-9acc-32c7f10d14a2",
    "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME}": "Wed Jun 10 15:27:42 2020 CEST",
    "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE}": "was successful",
    "{#CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES}": "0",
    "{#LAST_SUCCESS}": "Wed Jun 10 15:27:42 2020 CEST",
    "{#NTDS_DN}": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SCGPN0002,CN=Servers,CN=NOIRE,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=org",
    "{#IS_DELETED}": "false",
    "{#DSA}": "POINTE-NOIRE\\SCGPN0002-R2"
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Thanks @peak :) now is perfect

Comment: Which version of `jq` do you use?

Comment: `jq 1.6` centos 7

Comment: This might help: [Using jq how can I replace the name of a key with something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48412767/3776858)

Answer (score 11):

The following meets the requirements without the overhead of `walk`:

```
map(with_entries( .key |= ( gsub( " "; "_")
                            | ascii_upcase 
                            | "{#\(.)}" )
                  | .value |= tostring))
```

#### Caveat

As the name suggests, `ascii_upcase` only uppercases ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Cyrus i found one solution... i do not this is very "elegant" but is working!

```
cat myjsonfile.txt | jq 'walk( if type == "object" then with_entries( .key |= ( gsub( " "; "_") | ascii_upcase | "{#" + . +"}" )) else . end )'
```

Sorry @Cyrus i delete your suggestion

Comment: sorry.. is not perfect. CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES and IS_DELETED are without quotes...

Answer (score 0):

after several hours of work I have to change my approach...
The original json is:

```
{
  "dsa": {
    "options": 1,
    "objectGUID": "373f09c9-43ab-489b-9bed-c5357fbe37df",
    "invocationId": "e0e99a5d-9162-4c96-93e1-939976bee141"
  },
  "repsFrom": [
    {
      "NC dn": "DC=company,DC=org",
      "DSA objectGUID": "df9e8712-98c5-42e4-a020-2e5218404e51",
      "last attempt time": "Thu Jun 11 14:27:42 2020 CEST",
      "last attempt message": "was successful",
      "consecutive failures": 1,
      "last success": "Thu Jun 11 14:27:42 2020 CEST",
      "NTDS DN": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=STEN0002-R2,CN=Servers,CN=TENGIZ,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "is deleted": false,
      "DSA": "TENGIZ\\STEN0002-R2"
    },
    {
      "NC dn": "DC=company,DC=org",
      "DSA objectGUID": "d5d168fd-5fc3-4afc-9acc-32c7f10d14a2",
      "last attempt time": "Thu Jun 11 14:27:43 2020 CEST",
      "last attempt message": "was successful",
      "consecutive failures": 1,
      "last success": "Thu Jun 11 14:27:43 2020 CEST",
      "NTDS DN": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SCGPN0002-R2,CN=Servers,CN=POINTE-NOIRE,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "is deleted": false,
      "DSA": "POINTE-NOIRE\\SCGPN0002-R2"
    }
  ],
  "repsTo": [
    {
      "NC dn": "DC=company,DC=org",
      "DSA objectGUID": "86f053eb-36d7-41e4-b944-7bcd9fcb8aaa",
      "last attempt time": "NTTIME(0)",
      "last attempt message": "was successful",
      "consecutive failures": 1,
      "last success": "NTTIME(0)",
      "NTDS DN": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SMX0840002-R4,CN=Servers,CN=MX084,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "is deleted": false,
      "DSA": "MX084\\SMX0840002-R4"
    },
    {
      "NC dn": "DC=company,DC=org",
      "DSA objectGUID": "6e98ac67-389b-488a-ae3e-abf36d38ba73",
      "last attempt time": "NTTIME(0)",
      "last attempt message": "was successful",
      "consecutive failures": 0,
      "last success": "NTTIME(0)",
      "NTDS DN": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SCZ0002,CN=Servers,CN=CZ003,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "is deleted": false,
      "DSA": "CZ003\\SCZ0002"
    }
  ],
  "NTDSConnections": [
    {
      "name": "dc6118e7-eca5-4c2c-8248-2e762104e95a",
      "remote DN": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SPRLIMA0002-R2,CN=Servers,CN=PR-LIMA,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "options": 1,
      "enabled": true,
      "dns name": "sprlima0002-r2.company.org",
      "replicates NC": []
    },
    {
      "name": "9aa7d28f-5b08-42fe-960a-073c8ebfa4fb",
      "remote DN": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SMX0840002-R4,CN=Servers,CN=MX084,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "options": 1,
      "enabled": true,
      "dns name": "smx0840002-r4.company.org",
      "replicates NC": []
    },
  ]
}
```

this is the output of **samba-tool drs showrepl --json** what i need is:

- all key with out space and uppercase with {#JSON_KEY}
- CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES value and IS_DELETED value with " "
- see only item with CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES > 0 in one single array

something like this:

```
[
    {
      "{#NC_DN}": "DC=company,DC=org",
      "{#DSA}_OBJECTGUID}": "df9e8712-98c5-42e4-a020-2e5218404e51",
      "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME}": "Thu Jun 11 14:27:42 2020 CEST",
      "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE}": "was successful",
      "{#CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES}": "1",
      "{#LAST_SUCCESS}": "Thu Jun 11 14:27:42 2020 CEST",
      "{#NTDS_DN}": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=STEN0002-R2,CN=Servers,CN=TENGIZ,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "{#IS_DELETED}": "false",
      "{#DSA}": "TENGIZ\\STEN0002-R2"
    },
    {
      "{#NC_DN}": "DC=company,DC=org",
      "{#DSA}_OBJECTGUID}": "d5d168fd-5fc3-4afc-9acc-32c7f10d14a2",
      "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME}": "Thu Jun 11 14:27:43 2020 CEST",
      "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE}": "was successful",
      "{#CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES}": "1",
      "{#LAST_SUCCESS}": "Thu Jun 11 14:27:43 2020 CEST",
      "{#NTDS_DN}": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SCGPN0002-R2,CN=Servers,CN=POINTE-NOIRE,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "{#IS_DELETED}": "false",
      "{#DSA}": "POINTE-NOIRE\\SCGPN0002-R2"
    },
    {
      "{#NC_DN}": "DC=company,DC=org",
      "{#DSA}_OBJECTGUID}": "86f053eb-36d7-41e4-b944-7bcd9fcb8aaa",
      "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME}": "NTTIME(0)",
      "{#LAST_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE}": "was successful",
      "{#CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES}": "1",
      "{#LAST_SUCCESS}": "NTTIME(0)",
      "{#NTDS_DN}": "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SMX0840002-R4,CN=Servers,CN=MX084,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=org",
      "{#IS_DELETED}": "false",
      "{#DSA}": "MX084\\SMX0840002-R4"
    }
  ]
}
```

One sigle array with all errrors.

Thanks!!!