# format a json key-value pair's first field

Tags: json, zabbix

I have a json output I'd like to convert to a Zabbix parameter.

Basically, I need to transform something like the following:

```
"key":"value"
```

into something like this:

```
"#{KEY}":"value"
```

Leaving everything else untouched.

That is, I need to convert the first field to uppercase, surround it with square brackets and add a hash before the first bracket.

I've tried some combinations of sed, awk and grep, but things quickly got too long and messy to do so effectively.

I'm really unfamiliar with json and sparesly deal with it - I'd really appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!

EDIT: link below has solved this. To clarify, this is from a bash environment.

Comment: `I've tried some combinations of sed, awk and grep, but things quickly got too long and messy to do so effectively`. It's very appreciated on this forum to post what have you researched and what have you tried, even if it failed.

Comment: So, are you saying you need to do this from inside Zabbix? Asking for any solution in any programming language seems a bit too broad for this site, so it would be good to be a bit more specific.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312365/jq-key-map-name-to-uppercase-and-remove-space does this answer your question? It just has `#` inside, so a little change from `{#\(.)}` to `#{\(.)}` is needed.

Comment: Thank you both the rapid responses! @KamilCuk, that question was exactly it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQ key map name to uppercase and remove space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312365/jq-key-map-name-to-uppercase-and-remove-space)